# escape double quotes in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I'm trying to load the data using copy into command. Field has special character as value `\"`, but 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY its escaping `\` and getting error while loading

```
Found character '0' instead of field delimiter ';'
```

**DATA:**

```
"TOL";"AANVR. 1E K ZIE RF.\";"011188"
```

After escaping second column value its considering and escaping delimiter `AANVR. 1E K ZIE RF.\";` but actually it should be `AANVR. 1E K ZIE RF.\`.

**File format**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT TEST                  
       FIELD_DELIMITER = ';'                                                                                                                                         
       SKIP_HEADER = 1                                                                                                                                         
       TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYYHH24:MI:SS'                                                                                                                                         
       escape = "\\"                                                                                                                                '
       TRIM_SPACE = TRUE                                                                                                                                         
       FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\"'                                                                                                                                         
       NULL_IF = ('')                                                                                                                                         
       ENCODING = "iso-8859-1"                                                                                                                                         
 ;
```

Comment: Does it work if you fix the typo on your `escape` parameter?

Comment: And I don't think you need a \ in the `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY` parameter.

Comment: @MikeWalton FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\"' is required because other records having data like  "TOL";"RPC' 'B1XQ\" ";"011189"

Comment: But wouldn't you just want to use: `= '"'` there for that?

Comment: still getting same error with : = '"'

Comment: If you don't actually have  any escapes in your file, then set `escape = NONE` and see if that handles it better.

Comment: Tried with escape=none aswell still getting error

Answer (score 3):

If you need to replace double quotes in an existing table, you can use `'\"'` syntax in `replace` function. Example provided below.

```
select replace(column_name,'\"','') as column_name from table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Rough example, but the below works for me.  Let me know if you're looking for a different output.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE table DOUBLE_TEST_DATA (
   string1 string
 , varchar1 varchar
 , string2 string
 );                                                                                                                               

COPY INTO DOUBLE_TEST_DATA FROM @TEST/doublequotesforum.csv.gz
FILE_FORMAT = (
  TYPE=CSV
, FIELD_DELIMITER = ';' 
, FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'
);

select * from DOUBLE_TEST_DATA;
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought, as well, but OP is saying these cause the error stated.  It worked cleanly for me, though.

Comment: @MikeWalton Came up with two scenarios with two datasets Dateset1: "WESY";"AANVR. 1E K ZIE RF.\";"011188"; "CYDC67";"JV#19171455\\";"266020337000"; Dateset2: "SHI";"COMPLEX \"C\"";"OPT TM 16/12"; "PBMG";"BITTE WOHNUNG";"\"GLOCKNER\""; Dataset1 load fine with FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' and escape= None but getting error for Dateset2 Dataset2 load fine with FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY ='"' and escape='\\' but getting error for Dateset1

Comment: @marjun Sure, I can run with that example.  What output are you looking to get from this second dataset? In other words, what do you want it to look like after it's done loading?

Comment: @Suzy Lockwood Input Dataset1 :"AANVR. 1E K ZIE RF.\"
Expected Output: AANVR. 1E K ZIE RF.\


Input Dataset2 : "\"GLOCKNER\""
Output Dataset2: "GLOCKNER" 

Is it possible to load the both Datasets with one file format with Escape=None and Escape='\\'?

Comment: @marjun Unfortunately no, because you are telling the program to run conflicting escapes. It will not know in which situations you want to escape (the second dataset) and which situations you don't want to escape (first dataset).

Comment: @Suzy Lockwood found out temp solution, I have created two temporary tables and loaded data with two file formats with and without escape into each and loaded both table into to main table by removing duplicates.